# Are questions regarding modded game systems, including homebrew, considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

As the title suggests.....

By modded consoles, I mean consoles that have either hard or soft mods on them, such Free McBoot and RGH respectively. Additionally, by homebrew, I mean applications like OPL and ESR for the PS2.

Comment: Considering we have a tag for [tag:homebrew] I would say it's probably fine. Homebrew stuff draws a fine line between Arqade and Superuser though, so make sure to keep your question based around games (ie. if you were going to homebrew a PS2 to use as a PC, or as a media station or something, I would consider that off topic).

Comment: @Kaizerwolf, I honestly didn't know Arqade had a homebrew tag